# extend php with java/c++?

Tags: java, php, c++, python, php-extension

i only know php and i wonder if you can extend a php web application with c++ or java when needed? i dont want to convert my code with quercus, cause that is very error prone. is there another way to extend it?

cause from what i have read python can extend it with c++ without converting the python code and use java with jython?

Comment: For what purpose you need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of PHP is written in modular C code. You can create your own PHP extensions in C. See http://php.net/internals, the [PHP wiki](http://wiki.php.net/internals/engine) and the book "Extending and Embedding PHP" by Sara Golemon.